# Did West Pakistan not factor in Indian miltary intervention when it cracked down on East Pakistan in 1971?

Tags: war, india, pakistan

When West Pakistan launched "Operation Searchlight" to quell Bengali dissidents in March 1971, did the think-tank know that India would soon be involved in the war?

Did they not forsee that their operations would create thousands of refugees, who would definitely turn to India for aid?

If not, how could they think that India would not get militarily involved?

And if yes, what preparations did they make to counter Indian intervention?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Answer (score 1):

India had been involved in East Pakistan's affairs way before 1971.

According to the book [The Agartala Doctrine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199463808), the then Awami League leader Sheikh Mujibur Rahman and his compatriots were in contact with Indian authorities from 5th February 1962. This gave rise to the famous [*Agartala Conspiracy Case*](https://en.banglapedia.org/index.php/Agartala_Conspiracy_Case). Why Ayub Khan was unsuccessful in trying Sheikh Mujib is a different debate.

Next, according to the book [Creation of Bangladesh: Myths Exploded](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9692316904), India first started an assault on the integrity of Pakistan by executing a planned and systematic propaganda campaign as early as the 1960s.

Next, according to [the interview of ex-KGB officer Yuri Bezmeanov](https://youtu.be/yErKTVdETpw), the Soviet Union actively assisted the Awami League with money, training, and weapons via India.

Now come to your main question,

> Did West Pakistan not factor in Indian military intervention when it cracked down on East Pakistan in 1971?

According to the book *Creation of Bangladesh: Myths Exploded*, Mukti Bahini, and Awami League activists were trained in Uzbekistan and Kazakhstan and were supplied arms by KGB via India. The Chatra League activists stashed Soviet-made weapons in Dhaka University's Iqbal Hall.

On the 25th of March, they flew Bangladesh's flag and started mass plundering banks and non-Bengali homes, killing non-Bengalis, and burning trains and buses, mainly in Dhaka City and elsewhere in the country. Operation Searchlight was the response to this anarchy.

In August 1971, the Pakistan government published [a full report on the perpetrators of the anarchy](https://www.scribd.com/document/51195547/White-Paper-East-Pakistan-GOP-MMR) that started on 25th March 1971. However, because of Indian military intervention, those persons were never tried.

> what preparations did they make to counter Indian intervention?

Nothing special.

Then-president Gen. Yahya Khan was warned by his intelligence agencies not to start any preemptive attack. However, Gen. Yahya Khan didn't pay heed to them.

Given the Indian and Soviet activity at home and in the UN and the USA's total engagement of resources in Vietnam, Indian intervention was inevitable. The pre-emptive attack on India by Pakistan on 3rd December 1971 made the inevitable approach faster. Nothing else.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138708/discussion-on-answer-by-user366312-did-west-pakistan-not-factor-in-indian-miltar).